# SQL: How to find clusters of related items?

Tags: sql

We have a schema of the following form:

```
CREATE TABLE p (
  id int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO p (id) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pi (
  product_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  value varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (product_id, value)
);

INSERT INTO pi (product_id, value) VALUES
(1, 'a'),
(1, 'b'),
(2, 'a'),
(3, 'b'),
(4, 'c'),
(5, 'd'),
(5, 'e'),
(6, 'd');
(6, 'e');
```

A product can have several identifiers.

We want to create clusters of products that share the same identifiers. For example:

```
Product 1
  ID a
  ID b

Product 2
  ID a

Product 3
  ID b
```

Although products 2 and 3 are seemingly unrelated, by inspecting product 1 we find that all three products belong to each other, because they belong to the same identifiers group.

The result should be disconnected clusters of products where each product belongs to exactly one group. For the example data above I want to get the following product clusters:

```
1, 2, 3
4
5, 6
```

Is there any way to achieve this in pure SQL?

We haven't decided on an engine yet, so any open-source SQL database dialect would be acceptable.

Comment: Can you give a bit more sample data? Currently I have a hard time understanding what you are after (sounds as if a recursive query could achieve what you want)

Comment: you probably can do it coding some complex stored procedure, but the code will be hard to write and hard to maintain, while if you decide to write some code to do that, you'll be able to reuse lots of existent components and try different clustering algorithms. Some machine learning frameworks do have DB connectivity (such as Weka). My 2c

Comment: I've added some real SQL sample data to clarify. Stored procedures would be quite acceptable since we're looking at millions of records. I'll have a look at Weka in the meantime...

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly for fun and only clusters one level. It works for the provided sample data, likely not your real data. Performance is probably not good either. Assumes PostgreSQL.

```
select
array_agg(gp.product_id)
from (
  select
  productat_id,
  array_agg(value)
  from pi
  group by product_id
) as gp
left join (
  select
  product_id,
  array_agg(value)
  from pi
  group by product_id
  having count(*)>1
) gp2
on gp.array_agg && gp2.array_agg 
and gp.product_id <> gp2.product_id
group by coalesce(gp2.array_agg, gp.array_agg);

 array_agg 
-----------
 {1,3,2}
 {5,6}
 {4}
(3 rows)
```